# How do you make self-consistent initial values?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, causality

In electrodynamics for each charge you need to have data for everything in its past light cone. But the union of all past light cones for all charges would be a spacetime volume rather than a spacetime surface? So how do you ensure your initial data fulfills the dynamics, since you need to know the history of each charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the initial position and momenta of all charges, plus the analogous quantities for the electric and magnetic fields, at one initial time, is sufficient to determine the motion of the charges and fields at all later times (using the [retarded Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Advanced_and_retarded_Green%27s_functions)), **and at all earlier times** (using the advanced Green's function).

So you don't need to know in advance the complete history of the charges and fields up to some initial time. You just need to know the initial conditions at one time.

There is a subtlety with specifying initial data in electromagnetism; namely, there are [constraints](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/e96/PAPERS/TUPG/TUP117G.PDF) on the initial data, which means you aren't completely free to specify all the components of the electric and magnetic fields, and their first time derivatives, as well as the positions and momenta of the charges, at the initial time. The physical meaning of this is that you can freely specify the positions and momenta of the charges, and two components of the fields and two time derivatives corresponding to the initial configuration of the two independent propagating polarizations of the electromagnetic field, and then the rest of the components of the fields and their time derivatives at the initial time are determined by a subset of Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to clarify has nothing to do with the initial values' self-consistency but with the correct conditions ensuring the existence of a well-posed problem of existence, uniqueness, and continuous dependence of the solution of a hyperbolic set of partial differential equations (PDF) on the initial data.

Your initial statement is not correct. First of all, the conditions are not limited to the set of space-time points influencing a (point-like) charge, but we need to be able to determine the *fields*, even if, at some point, there is no charge. Moreover, it is not true that we

> need to have data for everything in its past light cone.

Maxwell's equations, once one removes some redundancies (the electric and magnetic fields are not controlled by six independent scalar functions. To eliminate the redundant degrees of freedom, one must move from a description using the ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}$ fields to a description in terms of electromagnetic potentials, choosing a gauge. However, such a set is not conceptually relevant to your problem. What matters is that the final set of equations remains a set of hyperbolic PDFs for functions defined in space-time.

For such a set of equations [Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy-Kovalevskaya_theorem) holds: initial data can be assigned on every hypersurface that is never tangent to a characteristic surface. In practice, in our case, characteristic surfaces are the light cones. Therefore, every space-time hypersurface (made by points separated by space-like distances) can be used. The simplest of such non-characteristic surfaces is a volume of all the simultaneous space points in a given Lorentz reference frame.

Comment: Your initial sentence seem self contradictory? A well posed problem requires the data to fulfill the pde, i.e. be self consistent. Please rephrase to make sense.

Comment: How is a field not contained in "everything in its past light cone"? Surely everything is a large enough set to contain a subset of everything (i.e. a tensor field or whatever).

Comment: I don't understand how you manage to escape needing data in the past light cone when the pdes have explicit dependence on it.

Comment: @Emil self-consistent == consistent with itself. For example, a self-consistent solution of a non-linear ode allows an exact cancellation between different terms of the equation. The case of the initial data is quite different. Sometimes, it may be recast in terms of self-consistency, but this is not an obliged step.

Comment: @Emil About data in the past light cone. Use the prototype of a vibrating string (D'Alemebert's equation). A well-posed problem implies that we provide the initial shape of the string and the initial time derivative at each point of the string. I.e. the  displacement field and its local velocity at time $t=0$. This is not the whole content of the light cone. The light cone, in this case, would contain configurations and velocities of the field at each space point *for all the previous times*. We need data at one time.

Comment: Initial with respect to what observer? What do you mean with time t, do you mean the proper time for the observer when the photon is reaching the observers position or do you mean the 'backwardly propagated position along the past lightcone'